# Is it possible to append data:video on video tag HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, filereader

I am having very problems with this append method on Video tag.

In img, I can easily append the src with the data:image like this:

```
<img id='imgprv' width='100%' hidden>
var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        // set data img to src
        var fileStatus = e.target.result.split('/')[0].split(':')[1];
        if (fileStatus == "image") {
            $("#imgprv").attr("src",e.target.result);
        }
    }
}
```

But when append to video tag, it can't appear. It's just a white blank.
Any idea how to append the data:video to video tag src?

```
<video width='400' controls> 
      <source type='video/mp4' id='vidprv'>
</video>
var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        // set data video to src
        var fileStatus = e.target.result.split('/')[0].split(':')[1];
        if (fileStatus == "video") {
            $("#vidprv").attr("src",e.target.result);
        }
    }
}
```

What i mean by FileReader value is like this:

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

Thank You :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something useful. After I change the URL, the Video must be reloaded.

```
<video width='400' controls id='vidhdr' hidden> <source type='video/mp4' id='vidprv'> </video>

else if (fileStatus == "video") {
    $("#vidhdr").removeAttr('hidden');
    $("#vidprv").attr("src",e.target.result);
    $("#vidhdr")[0].load();
}
```

why using [0] because of the first child --> `<source type='video/mp4' id='vidprv'>` must be reloaded

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you got the `this.files[0]` in your code, you might want to not use the file reader at all and instead pass it to `URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])` and be done.

Below is a working example with html and js. which can be tested here [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ahdxk8up/)

```
<video width='400' controls> 
      <source type='video/mp4' id='vidprv'>
</video>
<br>
<input type="file" value="find the file">
<br>
<button>Play</button>
```

```
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', play)
function play() {
  var video = document.querySelector('video');
  var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];

  // you can use your this.files[0] like so: 
  // const url = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]) 

  const url = URL.createObjectURL(file)          // this here is all there is to it!

  video.src = url
  video.play()
}
```

Also, this question might be close to what you need: [playing html5 video from in memory source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32017595/playing-html5-video-from-in-memory-source)

Comment: well I don't think, it will be played from memory source. actually I do this for temporary used. it will be used for preview only :). when it up to be saved, I will save the file in the host folder and save the filename on DB. for the button, I think its a good idea for implementing it but it is enough for me to just implementing what I have archieve right now. Thanks!